# Cannot implicitly convert type bool?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am trying to convert my nullable bool value and I am getting this error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**For example:**

```
public virtual bool? MyBool
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

if (!MyBool){}
```

Comment: In short, nullable bools are confusing.  (just look at SQL)

Comment: I don't think this is too confusing, it is just Ternary Logic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic - I actually like it because I like the notion of something having no value. In other words, uninitialized vs. initialized.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As the error states, you can't use a `bool?` in a conditional.  (What would happen if it's `null`?)

Instead, you can write `if (MyBool != true)` or `if (MyBool == false)`, depending on whether you want to include `null`.  (and you should add a comment explaining that)

Comment: Another valid check is `MyBool ?? false`, although I generally prefer `MyBool.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: However, that requires extra parentheses for negation, and is also more confusing.

Comment: I do not disagree on the first, but I don't find the second any more difficult to use or understand. Generally, I do not like direct comparisons to true or false, although I do exactly that in Linq-to-EF queries because the method is not supported.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use MyBool.Value

for example:

```
if (!MyBool.Value) { }
```

However, you should test that it does indeed have a value to begin with.  This tests that MyBool has a value and it is false.

```
if (MyBool.HasValue && !MyBool.Value) { }
```

Or you might really want the following that runs the code block if it either has not been assigned or has is false.

```
if (!MyBool.HasValue || !MyBool.Value) { }
```

The question really boils down to whether you truly intended to have a nullable boolean variable and, if so, how you want to handle the 3 possible conditions of `null, true or false`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if it has a value. What do you want to do if `MyBool == null`?

```
if( MyBool.HasValue && !MyBool.Value ) // MyBool is false
if( MyBool.HasValue && MyBool.Value ) // MyBool is true
if( !MyBool.HasValue ) // MyBool is null
```