# Why am i getting an error when i try to put a null check in my code

Tags: c#

The code given below is giving the following error when I put a ? or null checker on airUserCreditCardList.
cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
bookingInfo.CreditCardList = airUserCreditCardList
    ?.Any(item => item.Text.ToLower().Contains("primary")) 
    ? airUserCreditCardList
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(o => o.Text)
        .ToList() 
    : airUserCreditCardList.ToList();
```

What should the fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680391/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-bool-to-bool-an-explicit-conversion-exists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot implicitly convert type bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089536/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-bool)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `null` before using `Any` extension:

```cs
// assuming airUserCreditCartList is in fact an argument to your method
if (airUserCreditCartList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(airUserCreditCardList));

bookingInfo.CreditCardList = airUserCreditCardList
    .Any(item => item.Text.ToLower().Contains("primary")) 
    ? airUserCreditCardList
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(o => o.Text)
        .ToList() 
    : airUserCreditCardList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
        bookingInfo.CreditCardList = airUserCreditCardList
?.Any(item => item.Text.ToLower().Contains("primary")) == true
? airUserCreditCardList
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(o => o.Text)
    .ToList() 
: airUserCreditCardList.ToList();
```

The condition in the "ternary" operator expects a boolean expression.
But yours returns a `Nullable<bool>` aka `bool?`, because of the "Elvis" operator.

To make it a boolean expression compare the return of "`?.Any(...)`" to `true`.